# VirtualBox won't show the Virtual Machines Sidebar in the Manager Window

Tags: ubuntu, virtualbox, virtual-machine, download

When attempting to create a new VM for a SEED lab using VirtualBox on a MacBook intel i7. I must have accidentally clicked something, because my VirtualBox window that *should* show me where my virtual machines are is gone.

I can navigate between other windows, such as the Network Manager or the Virtual Media Manager by going to [File->Tools]. I can also Add or Create machines by going to "Machines" in the menu bar. However, I can't start any of my machines, there were 3 including the one I just made, because I simply cannot find them within VirtualBox.

So far...
I have tried quitting, waiting for a variety of time periods, and reopening VirtualBox; this results in the same window/view I saw before closing it opens again.

I have tried nicely restarting my computer, waiting, and reopening VirtualBox; this has the same result as simply quitting the application.

I have tried deleting VirtualBox and all associated data, restarting the computer, and redownloading VirtualBox; this somehow still has the same result as the previous things I have tried.

I have included a picture of the VirtualBox Manager Window showing only the Network Manager. A list including "Tools" and my VMs usually sit on the left under the circle buttons next to the Manager.

[image: NetworkManager]

Comment: Please see this article:   https://forums.virtualbox.org/viewtopic.php?t=92079

Comment: Run the following command **VBoxManage setextradata global "GUI/SplitterSizes"**